# Find HTML Class and Remove it Based off Text?

Tags: javascript, html

EDIT: I thought I'd add at the top here the reason I'm doing this is that the filter for Reddit Enhancement Suite doesn't work for me and I don't need all the other features of it anyways.

I'm trying to create a browser extension for my own personal use that filters subreddits on reddit that I don't want to see. I've done quite a bit of Googling and gotten to the point where I can remove the post with the div id like this:

```
var element = document.querySelector("div.divid");
element.parentElement.removeChild(element);
```

So that works for deleting the post however each div id is unique to each post. Therefore this doesn't work to continuously delete posts from a specific subreddit.

Looking at the html of the page if I dig inside of the div that encapsulates the post I can find:

```
<a class="class_name" data-click-id="subreddit" href="/r/subredditname/">r/subredditname</a>
```

I've tried seeing if I can delete by the class name? Again, the class name is unique to each post. So what I'm wondering, as I can't seem to find the right wording to find an answer, can I using the code I have above to do:

```
var element = document.querySelectorAll("r/subredditname");
element.parentElement.removeChild(element);
```

or something along those lines to delete the entire post based solely off the text inside the class that displays the name of the subreddit inside the post?

Comment: You can take a look at attribute selectors; https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors (you can also query on classes but your example is the href, so attribute selector makes more sense)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I tried: document.querySelector("a[href*='/r/subredditname/']"); but that does not appear to do anything. Am I understanding the attributes incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

Okay I figured it out! Thanks to Rene's comment I revised it to be:

```
var element = document.querySelector("a[href*='/r/subredditname/']");
element.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.remove();
```

This works to mostly delete the entire post. It leaves behind a little line but it works. I'll have to revise it because spamming parentElement doesn't seem like the prettiest solution but thanks!